# How to paginate "Change List" page in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-admin, django-pagination

With my `admin.py` below, all items are shown on only one **Change List** page in Django admin:

`admin.py`:

```
from cliente.models import Cliente
from django.contrib import admin

class ClienteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome','bairro','endereco','telefone')
    list_filter = ('bairro',)
    ordering = ('nome',)
    search_fields = ('endereco',)   
    pass

admin.site.register(Cliente,ClienteAdmin)
```

Now, I want to paginate **Change List** page to show the specific number of items on each **Change List** page. So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

See [ModelAdmin.list_per_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page). The default is `100`, but you can set it to a lower value.

Answer (score 31):

Here I take example of **5 records per page**, you can change according to your requirement:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    list_per_page = 5 # No of records per page
```

Answer (score 4):

Here I take the example of 10 records per page, you can change according to your requirement:

```
class CK_Sub_CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display=('Sub_Category_Name','Parent_Category_Name')
   search_fields=('Sub_Category_Name','Parent_Category_Name')
   list_filter=('Sub_Category_Name','SC_Published_Date')
   actions=[make_inactive,make_active]
   list_per_page=10 #record 10 per page
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [list_per_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page) to list the specific number of items on each paginated **Change List** page. By default, `100` is set to `list_per_page`.

And, you can also set [list_max_show_all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_max_show_all) to show or hide **Show all** link on each paginated **Change List** page. By default, `200` is set to `list_max_show_all`. ***Show all** link appears if `list_max_show_all` value is more than or equal to total items while **Show all** link disappears if `list_max_show_all` value is less than total items.

For example, there is `Person` model below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And, there is `Person` admin below:

```py
# "admin.py"

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, all `7` persons are listed as shown below:

[image]

Now, I set `list_per_page = 4` to `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 4 # Here
```

Then, `4` persons are listed on the 1st page as shown below:

[image]

And, `3` persons are listed on the 2nd page as shown below:

[image]

Next, I click on **Show all** link as shown below:

[image]

Then, all `7` persons are listed as shown below:

[image]

Next, I set `list_max_show_all = 6` to `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 4
    list_max_show_all = 6 # Here
```

Then, **Show all** link disappears as shown below because `list_max_show_all` value `6` is less than the total persons `7`:

[image]