# Paginator for inline models in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have this simple django model consisting of an sensor and values for the specific sensor.
The number of values per Pyranometer is high (>30k). Is it somehow possible to paginate `PyranometerValues` by a specific day or generell apply a paginator to the admin inline view?

```
class Pyranometer(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=75)                                                                             

class PyranometerValues(models.Model):                                                                                 
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=6)                                                        
    sensor = models.ForeignKey('Pyranometer')
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
[django-admin-pagination-question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4987630/856070

Comment: @user856070 unfortunately no. My question is regarding an inline view and pagination. Unfortunately it seems that there is no way to paginate the objects for a inline view per default

Comment: Sounds like your sensor page is not for editing the sensor values. If that's the case, I wouldn't use inlines in the first place. It would be better to override `change_form.html` and render a paginated sensor value list there using a custom template tag. Pass `app_label` and `object_id` to the template tag for looking up the sensor instance. See "Overriding admin templates" at http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: Agree with @akaihola. If you're not editing the data, just output it as a list.

Comment: The disadvantage with going down the custom list template route is that it's not DRY.  I've just duplicated all of the custom field formatting in a template for an InlineAdminModel because a) there's no pagination yet for Django admin inline models and b) the `max_num` value you can apparently set for the inline model (along with `extra`, `can_delete`, etc. fields) do not appear to work.  (Django version 1.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) attribute? I think you might find it useful.

Comment: Unfortunately the raw_id_field is something different. I use the raw_id_field for foreign keys which have a lot of data. But in this case i want to show some meta data about the pyranometer and below the PyranometerValues (InlineAdmin but paginated). TBH i thin i will do it all manually.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone requires this, I found this nice (though described as "quite hacky") implementation of a pagination `TabularInline` subclass in [this comment](https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/issues/65#issuecomment-29606850) of [a django-suit](https://github.com/darklow/django-suit) issue.

For Django 1.6 it requires a template change and subclassing this `PaginationInline` class:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, InvalidPage, Paginator

class InlineChangeList(object):
    can_show_all = True
    multi_page = True
    get_query_string = ChangeList.__dict__['get_query_string']

    def __init__(self, request, page_num, paginator):
        self.show_all = 'all' in request.GET
        self.page_num = page_num
        self.paginator = paginator
        self.result_count = paginator.count
        self.params = dict(request.GET.items())


class PaginationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    template = 'admin/edit_inline/tabular_paginated.html'
    per_page = 20

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset_class = super(PaginationInline, self).get_formset(
            request, obj, **kwargs)
        class PaginationFormSet(formset_class):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(PaginationFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

                qs = self.queryset
                paginator = Paginator(qs, self.per_page)
                try:
                    page_num = int(request.GET.get('p', '0'))
                except ValueError:
                    page_num = 0

                try:
                    page = paginator.page(page_num + 1)
                except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
                    page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

                self.cl = InlineChangeList(request, page_num, paginator)
                self.paginator = paginator

                if self.cl.show_all:
                    self._queryset = qs
                else:
                    self._queryset = page.object_list

        PaginationFormSet.per_page = self.per_page
        return PaginationFormSet
```

Answer (score 3):

**For any version of Django**, follow these steps:

1. Visit this file : `python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html` make a copy of it in your `app/templates/admin/edit_inline/anyname.html`

between `</table>` and `</fieldset>` tag add in **anyname.html**:

```
   <style>
    .dark {
      /*background-color: #417690;*/
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border: none;
      color: #666;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .light {
      background-color: #008CBA;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

  </style>
   <div>
   {% with inline_admin_formset.formset.page as page_obj %}
    <p class="paginator">
      {% if page_obj.previous_page_number > 1 %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number|add:'-1' }}">{% trans 'previous' %}</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"-5" > 0 %}
        <a href="?page=0">1</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"-5" > 1 %}
        <span>&hellip;</span>
      {% endif %}

      {% for page_num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == page_num %}
          <span class="dark">{{ page_num|add:"-1" }}</span>
        {% else %}
          {% if page_num > page_obj.number|add:"-5" and page_num < page_obj.number|add:"5" %}
            <a class="light" style="color:white" href="?page={{ page_num|add:'-1' }}">{{ page_num|add:"-1" }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"5" < page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
        <span>&hellip;</span>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"4" < page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.next_page_number < page_obj.paginator.num_pages|add:'1' %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number|add:'-1' }}">{% trans 'next' %}</a>
      {% endif %}
      <span class='dark'>{{ page_obj.paginator.count }} Queries</span>
    </p>
  {% endwith %}
  </div>
```

2.Go to your **admin.py** file:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, InvalidPage, Paginator

class InlineChangeList(object):
    can_show_all = True
    multi_page = True
    get_query_string = ChangeList.__dict__['get_query_string']

    def __init__(self, request, page_num, paginator):
        self.show_all = 'all' in request.GET
        self.page_num = page_num
        self.paginator = paginator
        self.result_count = paginator.count
        self.params = dict(request.GET.items())


class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    per_page = 10
    template = 'admin/edit_inline/anyname.html'
    model = Mymodel
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset_class = super(MyInline, self).get_formset(
            request, obj, **kwargs)
        class PaginationFormSet(formset_class):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(PaginationFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

                qs = self.queryset
                paginator = Paginator(qs, self.per_page)
                try:
                    page_num = int(request.GET.get('page', ['0'])[0])
                except ValueError:
                    page_num = 0

                try:
                    page = paginator.page(page_num + 1)
                except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
                    page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

                self.page = page
                self.cl = InlineChangeList(request, page_num, paginator)
                self.paginator = paginator

                if self.cl.show_all:
                    self._queryset = qs
                else:
                    self._queryset = page.object_list

        PaginationFormSet.per_page = self.per_page
        return PaginationFormSet
```

Answer (score 2):

The [django-admin-inline-paginator](https://github.com/shinneider/django-admin-inline-paginator) paginated inlines in my case efficiently.

---

I have an item with 900 related items of the same kind that must be displayed as inlines. Before using that package I was getting 502 because nginx timed out before uwsgi was able to create a response.
Using this package helped me decrease drastically the response time although I am sure I will still have problems with a lot of traffic

Just for reference, the error I was getting from uwsgi is:

```
DAMN ! worker 3 (pid: 19) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 3 (new pid: 22)
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request <> (ip <>) !!!
uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 341] during GET <> (<>)
OSError: write error
```

Answer (score 1):

As django-admin is mainly a matter of templates (only needed to redefine templates to i18n some django-admin-tools parts), I have an idea.

The are pagination modules for Django, like linaro-django-pagination or endless-pagination, which provide template tags to paginate anything given it is iterable.

If you could find the template in charge of displaying inline models, you could copy it in your project, then try adding a {% load pagination_tags %} to it and paginate the inlines.

I have not tested it nor thought it very thoroughly but except for validation, I don't see how it could fail. Just test and tell us.

Comment: I finally tested it and it seems it is not that simple because the InlineAdminFormSet uses a generator for its __iter__ operator, which returns InlineAdminForms...

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe dynamically generated filters would help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Also, the admin has a nice GET-type query as in:

localhost:8000/admin/pyranometervalues/?value=10.0

You could specify the date as:

admin/pyranometervalues/?timestamp_*year=2011&timestamp*_month=10&timestamp__day=13

and so on... Unfortunately I don't know a shorter way to make this query in admin. Any ideas? :)

EDIT: this is only for narrowing your query, doesn't have anything to do with pagination ;)

Answer (score 0):

Correct update for this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/60874181/22464874

For any version of Django, follow these steps:

1. Visit this file : python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html make a copy of it in your app/templates/admin/edit_inline/anyname.html
   between  and  tag add in anyname.html:

```
<style>
    .dark {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border: none;
      color: #666;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .light {
      background-color: #008CBA;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
   <div>
   {% with inline_admin_formset.formset.page as page_obj %}
    <p class="paginator">
      {% if page_obj.number > 1 %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:"-1" }}">{% trans 'previous' %}</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"-5" > 0 %}
        <a href="?page=1">1</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"-5" > 0 %}
        <span>&hellip;</span>
      {% endif %}

      {% for page_num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == page_num %}
          <span class="dark">{{ page_num }}</span>
        {% else %}
          {% if page_num > page_obj.number|add:"-5" and page_num < page_obj.number|add:"5" %}
            <a class="light" style="color:white" href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"5" < page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
        <span>&hellip;</span>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number|add:"4" < page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% if page_obj.number < page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.number|add:"1" }}">{% trans 'next' %}</a>
      {% endif %}
      <a class="light" href="?all">Показать все: {{ page_obj.paginator.count }} lines</a>
    </p>
  {% endwith %}
  </div>
```

2. Go to your admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, InvalidPage, Paginator

class InlineChangeList(object):
    can_show_all = True
    multi_page = True
    get_query_string = ChangeList.__dict__['get_query_string']

    def __init__(self, request, page_num, paginator):
        self.show_all = 'all' in request.GET
        self.page_num = page_num
        self.paginator = paginator
        self.result_count = paginator.count
        self.params = dict(request.GET.items())


class PaginationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    template = 'admin/edit_inline/tabular_paginated.html'
    per_page = 20

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset_class = super(MyInline, self).get_formset(
            request, obj, **kwargs
        )

        class PaginationFormSet(formset_class):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(PaginationFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

                qs = self.queryset
                paginator = Paginator(qs, self.per_page)
                try:
                    page_num = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    page_num = 1

                try:
                    page = paginator.page(page_num)
                except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
                    page = paginator.page(1)

                self.page = page
                self.cl = InlineChangeList(request, page_num, paginator)
                self.paginator = paginator

                if self.cl.show_all:
                    self._queryset = qs
                else:
                    self._queryset = page.object_list

        PaginationFormSet.per_page = self.per_page
        return PaginationFormSet
```

P. S.: I'd fix html to correct pagination, numeration from 1, and was a bug with openning the last page if it is not full