# Paginator for TabularInline models in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I checked this [Paginator for inline models in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664806/paginator-for-inline-models-in-django-admin) question but none of answers doesnt work for me. I use django 1.11 . Are there any other solution?

Comment: any examples if you tried any ?

Comment: I tried it https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/issues/65#issuecomment-29606850 but doesnt work

Comment: Share your code repo if it's an opensource. I will have a look.

Comment: Sorry my repo is commercial. In general i need pagination in tabularinline admin.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django-admin-inline-paginator](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-inline-paginator/), the plugin is super simple and straightforward.