# Django model admin custom get_queryset pagination is not working

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset, paginator, django-pagination

In my django code i am displaying user list with custom queryset:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs.filter(is_staff=0,is_superuser=0)
        paginator = Paginator(qs, 5)
        qs = paginator.get_page(1)
        return qs
```

i dont know what is getting wrong here but it is returning me the error like .

KeyError: 'request'

but when i remove the paginator from there it is working fine. here i want to use client side datatable pagimation for my user list .can anyone have any idea why i am getting this

Comment: Why don't you just use `list_per_page` attribute? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987688/11544538

Comment: @ErsainD. No beacuse i want to use datatable pagination.. after list_per_page i am not able to search through complete db in datatable search so i want to use datatable pagination.

Comment: You should show the full error trace.